# Why the request does not handled by this method in SpringMVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm following the demo in https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-tutorial. After running the demo on the tomcat server,I visited the url "http://localhost:8080/webTest1_war_exploded/",it seems the request is not handled by springmvc controller.

web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    public HelloController() {
    }

    @RequestMapping({"/"})
    public String display() {
        System.out.println("yes");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

after I visited the url: "http://localhost:8080/webTest1_war_exploded/", the console does not print "yes".
Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: What happens if you just go `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: got httpcode404,webTest1 is my project name.@SMA

Answer (score -1):

Just try to replace

```
@RequestMapping({"/"})
```

with

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```

Comment: it does not work.